# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext - connecting to database via DAL and service with generic repository and unit of work

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, unit-of-work

I have a data access layer (a C# library), a .NET Core application that I intend to use as a service and several projects that need to talk to this service, including a Blazor WASM project.

My DAL has a DbContext that looks like this:

```
public class QualityAssuranceDbContext : DbContext
{
    public QualityAssuranceDbContext(DbContextOptions<QualityAssuranceDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public QualityAssuranceDbContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Aspect> Aspects { get; set; }

    //PLUS OTHER ENTITIES REDACTED FOR BREVITY
}
```

Then in my separate .NET Core project I have an `appsettings.json` file with the connection string which I reference in `Program.cs` like so:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<QualityAssuranceDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

I'm using the generic repository/unit of work pattern so in my .NET Core project I also have a UnitOfWork class that looks like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private QualityAssuranceDbContext _context = new QualityAssuranceDbContext();
        
        private IBaseRepository<Aspect> _aspects;

        public IBaseRepository<Aspect> Aspects => _aspects ??= new BaseRepository<Aspect>(_context);

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public async Task Save(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            //DO STUFF
        }
    }
```

and a BaseRepository that looks like this:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly QualityAssuranceDbContext _context;
        private readonly DbSet<T> _db;

        public BaseRepository(QualityAssuranceDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _db = _context.Set<T>();
        }

        public async Task<IList<T>> GetAll(
                Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null,
                Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
                Func<IQueryable<T>, IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> includes = null
                )
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _db;

            if (expression != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(expression);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            if (includes != null)
            {
                query = includes(query);
            }

            return await query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }

        //PLUS OTHER CRUD ACTIONS        
    }
```

I then reference `UnitOfWork` in `Program.cs` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

Finally, in the server project of my Blazor WASM app I have a controller that looks like this:

```
public class QualityAssuranceController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly QualityAssuranceService _qualityAssuranceService;

    public QualityAssuranceController()
    {
        this._qualityAssuranceService = new QualityAssuranceService();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAspects(bool includeDeleted = false)
    {
        var claimsPrincipal = User;
        var schoolId = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "schoolId");

        if (schoolId != null)
        {
            var aspects = await _qualityAssuranceService.GetAspects(int.Parse(schoolId.Value), false);

            var aspectsDto = (from aspect in aspects
                              select new AspectDto()
                              {
                                  Name = aspect.Name,
                              }).ToList();

            return Ok(aspectsDto);
        }
        else
        {
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
}
```

The controller successfully calls my QualityAssuranceService which then tries to instantiate a new BaseRepository via my UnitOfWork. The point it seems to fail is:

```
_db = _context.Set<T>();
```

and the error message I'm getting when I check the network tab in developer tools is:

System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The provider is in the connection string.  It could be the driver of the Name (oledb, or similar) or the ODBC connection name.

Comment: You create a new instance of `QualityAssuranceDbContext` without passing the connection string in your UnitOfWork, instead of injecting it. This might be the culprit.

Comment: @IvanGechev yes I did wonder that, but if I inject it into my UnitOfWork, I'm not sure how I then handle that when passing the QualityAssuranceService to my controller?

Comment: @jdweng Sorry, I'm not sure I understand you. Are you saying the connection string might be incorrect? I've checked it and I'm sure it's fine. I use another similar connection string successfully elsewhere.

Comment: If it is a ODBC connection than your connection string and ODBC Data Source have to be consistent.  Go to Window Start button and type ODBC Data Source.

Comment: @HannahHayes Ideally you inject everything - `IUnitOfWork` into your `QualityAssuranceService`, `IQualityAssuranceService` into your `QualityAssuranceController` and register those in the `Program.cs`

Comment: @IvanGechev when I do that, it then fails to build and I get the following error message in my Blazor Server Program.cs: Unable to resolve service for type 'Hermes.DAL.QualityAssuranceDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Hermes.Services.QualityAssurance.UnitOfWork'. It seems pointless even having a separate DAL if I then also need to include the connection string and DbContext in my Blazor Server project?

Comment: @HannahHayes Did you inject the QualityAssuranceDbContext in the UnitOfWork, as you do for BaseRepository?

Comment: @IvanGechev Yes, I've done that.

Comment: @HannahHayes Without seeing the full code it's hard to tell what might be wrong.